# OpenCart Design option

Tags: opencart, opencart-3, opencart-module

I am working for an open cart Version 3.0.2.0 eCommerce website. The "Design" option is missing in the admin panel. Kindly suggest alternate an alternate way for enabling the "Design" option

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean yo don't have **Design** in admin panel left menu?

I think it could be lack of permissions. Open *System > Users > Users*, find your user and see what user group do you belong. Then go to *System > Users > User Group*. Here you will find your user group. Edit it. Mare sure all permissions start with **design/*** are checked. Save changes. Now you will might see **Design** in left menu.